# My game has a lot of errors of variables not being defined

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\FS2StratfordAC\ALIANWAR$\My Documents\Computing\A453 Controlled Assessment\Python\Task 3\dice game task 3 v2.py", line 52, in <module>
    print ("Your total is ", str_total)
NameError: name 'str_total' is not defined*
```

Here is half of my program.

```
if dice1 ==dice2:
    print (p1 +(" your skill is " + p1skill))
    print (p1 +(" your skill is " + p1str))
    print (p2 +(" your skill is " + p2skill))
    print (p2 +(" your skill is " + p2str))
if dice1 > dice2:
    str_total = (str_mod + p1str)
    skill_total=(skill_mod + p1skill)
    print (p1+ "Strength: " + str(str_val))
    print (p1+ "Skill: " + str(skill_val))
    print (p2+ "Strength: " + str(str_val))
    print (p2+ "Skill: " + str(skill_val))
if dice2 > dice1:
    str_total = (str_mod+p2str)
    skill_total=(skill_mod+p2skill)
    str_total = (str_mod+p2skill)
    str_total=(skill_mod + p1str)
    skill_total = (skill_mod - p1skill)

print ("Your total is ", str_total) 
print ("Your total is ", skill_total)
```

There are other things that are not defined like line 14 and line 21 which isn't defined. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks ;D.

Comment: I've tried to reconstruct your code while formatting it correctly for posting here. Can you please verify that the indentation still reflects your actual code?

Answer (score 2):

If `dice1 == dice2` is true, you never set `str_total` and `skill_total`.

When `dice2 > dice1` is true, however, you set `str_total` and `skill_total` *twice*.